# Is master in physics at Germany well respected in US?

Tags: phd, application, physics, germany

As a physics major in US, my PhD application is screwed up this year and neither did I found a decent job. So I'm thinking of applying for a two years master program in German, which provides more time in research (so that I have chance to collect better letters) while does not charge for tuition. Specifically I am interested in the program at Technical University of Munich and Ludwig Maximilian U, in area of theoretical/computational condensed matter physics and possibly computational material science. However I'm wondering does a master degree bring any negative effect in my future application for PhD in US? I heard people mentioned that US schools don't like master students quite much and see it as an incompetence somehow. So in general, is German a good destination? What are some other pros and cons you might already know? Thanks.

Comment: The reputation of university or institute is more important than where it located.

Answer (score 4):

Both of the universities you list are good with excellent reputations among the German universities. Furthermore, the German university system is well understood to provide a rigorous and high quality education.

So yes, do it -- it will make your future applications look better for sure. Furthermore, most graduate committees do value people studying abroad for a while since it shows dedication and ambition in an applicant.

There is of course no guarantee that you will be admitted in the future. But I can't think of a reason why it would not make your future applications look better.

Answer (score 0):

Those Universities - especially LMU - are European Ivy Leagues when it comes to physics. LMU has a very strong program on theoretical physics, so if you didn't get accepted in phd programs in US I kind doubt you will get into the master's program at LMU

Comment: This is more comment, rather than an answer. It is also your opinion, so... you could just downvote the question